# "So that Federer won there" is this correct grammar?

Tags: grammar

This sentence in the Heading of this news article just did not sound right to me and I'm confused if it's correct grammaticality?

What made it more confusing is the last line of the article, "so that he could win there". This wording sounds right to me.

Which one is correct?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it seems ok to me. What do you think is the problem? Although I must say that the English in the rest of the image is awkward and clearly not written by a fluent speaker.

Comment: @Chappo "Won" vs "could win"

Comment: *could win* is better. However, “so” could here be understood to mean “in order to produce the outcome” in which case the past tense “won” makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The word 'so' can have many meanings. In the headline I would interpret it as meaning, "in such a way that".

However the headline and indeed the article appear not to have been written by a native English speaker.

I imagine that they shortened the headline for page formatting reasons. The final sentence in the article is much better.